# Problems with products count in middle and top parent categories in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Products are not being correctly counted in categories.

Backoffice:

[image]

I checked in the *wp_term_taxonomy* table and I verified the same issue as founded in the backoffice.

I tried to switch theme, deactivate all plugins except WooCommerce, clear transient and recount terms but nothing is working.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

disable all theme/plugins apart from WooCommerce and then go
WooCommerce > Status > Tools > Term counts, click "Recount terms"
wait for terms to be recounted
now check if the problem is still there.

if not, reactivate theme/plugins and then check your term count.